# Does Inuyasha stop at episode 183?

Tags: inuyasha

I have been searching for a while but I couldn't find any episode lists, so I tried to look up another episode but nothing really came up.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Inuyasha_episodes) has a detailed episode list of both, Inuyasha and The Final Act. According to it, the series stops at Episode 193.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuyasha) Inuyasha has a total of 193 episodes. The first series has 167 episodes and the second series called The Final Act has 26 episodes.

> It was adapted into two anime television series produced by Sunrise. The first was broadcast for 167 episodes on Yomiuri TV in Japan from October 16, 2000 until September 13, 2004. The second series, called Inuyasha: The Final Act, began airing five years later on October 3, 2009 to cover the rest of the manga series and ended on March 29, 2010 after 26 episodes.

Here is a list of episodes for both series.

[Inuyasha](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Inuyasha_episodes)

[Inuyasha The Final Act](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Inuyasha:_The_Final_Act_episodes)